# Is there a way to partition Entity Framework EDMX's?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, edmx, edmx-designer

With a large model, it would be really useful to have multiple Entity Framework designer surfaces that address a particular domain (authentication, customFeature1, customFeature2, etc) and have those EDMX's reference entities in other EDMX's.

Is there a way to work with a paradigm similar to what you get with SQL Management Studio diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a new feature of EF Designer in Visual Studio 2012 - you still have single EDMX but you have multiple layouts (diagrams). [Here is preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx) of new features in the designer. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have this feature.

Referencing entities from other EDMX is possible only with very limited scope (only in CSDL)  and this feature is not supported by designer at all.